# Assigning string to a list

Tags: python, string, list

```
import random
import numpy as np
LOC = np.zeros(96)
LOC[0] = 'H'
for t in range(0,96):
    if 32<t<40:
            LOC[t] = random.choice(['H','W','I'])
```

Here, I want to initialize LOC with the character 'H' and has the check few conditions. But when I try to assign it, I am getting an error  `could not convert string to float: 'H'`. How can I assign a character/string to the list LOC?

Comment: `LOC = np.zeros(96, dtype="S1")` would give you an array that actually holds characters, rather than the default of floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy is not really made for mixing types of content. If you want an array of strings the empty values shouldn't be zero, but rather empty strings: `''`
You can use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to get the random values and assign, but the trick is to set the dtype to something that's appropriate for strings::

```
import random
import numpy as np

LOC = np.zeros(96, dtype='<U1')
LOC[0] = 'H'
LOC[32:40] = random.choices(['H','W','I'], k = 40 - 32)
```

This will be an array of empty strings except where you've assigned random values. Regular python lists, of course work with mixed types, if you don't need NumPy, you can initialize the array with:

```
LOC = [0] * 96
```

and then proceed with setting values with whatever you want.

Comment: So minor but I can't resist `random.choices("HWI", k = 96)`.

Comment: Yeah, that is nicer @ggorlen.

Comment: But that is not what he wants. He wants `LOC[0]=='H'` and only `LOC[33:40]` to be filled with random stuff.

Comment: Thanks @H.Doebler I read that too fast. Hopefully the edit is an improvement.

Comment: @H.Doebler Yes, that is exactly what I wanted and I got it by using the dtype specified above. Thank you so much

Comment: @MarkMeyer Got the necessary result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In python u can use the `ord` function to get the unicode code point of a charachter. So using

```
            LOC[t] = ord(random.choice(['H','W','I']))
```

you should be able to achieve your goal, even though I would call it 'assigning a character to a numpy array' and not 'assigning a string to a list'.